# In Kicad 7, how to start routing a track on click, rather than immediately?

Tags: kicad, user-interface

In Kicad 5, when one presses 'X', a track is not immediately created. Rather, one clicks in the workpiece to start the track.

I have recently upgraded to Kicad 7. Here, pressing 'X' on the keyboard starts a track immediately at the mouse location. This is undesirable.

Clicking on the "route tracks" toolbar button (to which 'X' is bound) has the behaviour I want. Oddly however, selecting "route single track" from the Route menu starts the track immediately.....from where the mouse was at the time of selecting the menu item. Seems a bit stupid.

I have looked in the hotkeys preferences; and googled; and come up empty. How can I go back to the previous behaviour? Short of pressing 'escape' all the time, I mean.

Comment: I think that's a good question, and the observation that starting a track from the cursor position when in the menu being useless actually justifies [filing a bug report with Kicad](https://forum.kicad.info/t/i-found-a-bug-what-now/9452). That community is *Fast* with a capital F, you might get that fixed, and the info how to do what you want (or a preference option to change to that behaviour or something) out of it as a sideproduct.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm frankly amazed at the rapid progress in Kicad compared to commercial offerings.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany right? The speed with with it overtook "pre-autodesk" Eagle was amazing. From zero to mostly equal or outcompeting Eagle is amazing. It's still a bit lacking on automation, layout-reuse, pre-production steps (panelling etc.), and simulation integration, but it's really not absurd to claim that at least for non-high-speed, normal-substrate projects, there's not that much reason to get an Altium license…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to select this option in your preferences

[image: first hotkey selects tool]

Comment: Yes! That fixed it. What an obscure option...!